# Problem with post a picture in Facebook Wall with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

I am using the Graph API for Facebook in order to post a message and a picture through my application to the user's wall. 
I use this one:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 
               'post', 
               array( 
                 'access_token' => $token, 
                 'message' => $message, 
                 'caption' => $caption, 
                 'description' => $description, 
                 'picture' => $picture, 
                 'cb' => ''
                )
              );
```

This works fine for around 4-5 months now. Suddenly I cannot post the picture. I haven't changed my code at all, but now I cannot see the image that is supposed to be posted.

I really don't know what is the problem. I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have seen this complient several times in the past few days. Maybe some kind of change in Facebook. Will try and check on this with my "inside man" for you and get back if I find anything.

Comment: Are the images taken from a blogger blog by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the image is not taken from any blog. Is an image produced by http://chart.apis.google.com if this helps.

Comment: Where is the picture hosted? FB stopped sIf it happens to be hosted on the FB site and served through their CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to use [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to pass google chart api url. As that consist of many special characters.

Comment: Actually I tried it also with another image and still didn't work. Also it worked before with the google image so the problem should not be the image.

Comment: **are you using updated access_token?** because if you are using older access_token then it may be possible it wont work.

Comment: How can I check this? I am using $token = $session['access_token'] as access_token.

Comment: You can do by adding below javascript code in your application (this will alert you access_token, if that matches then we need to think of another option...:) ):
`FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    alert(response.session.access_token);
  }
});
`

Comment: Or you can also check with graph api: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$token`

Comment: Well I add the token number in the $token in this link https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$token and it showed me information about me. Is this ok?

Comment: Then i suggest you 1 more thing... 
Use Curl or file_get_content on url: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=$token...all other parameter`
Atleast this should work... if not, let me know.. will try some other way... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Love Sharma. Today it starts working again without changing anything!!Very strange issue. Do you know how can I check in general if the access token is expired?

Comment: I suggest you to get latest copy of access_token when user logged into your application. and store that if you have offline-access. Rest you know... it seems you are champ in facebook developer... :)

Answer (score 1):

The feed will only allow you to upload small images.
Try a small image, if it works your probably need to post as image instead of wall post.