# the picture can't be attached when I publish a new feed on facebook by graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I  was publishing a new feed to the wall on facebook  using graph api in ruby, and it works except the picuture is blank.

here is a arguments  I attached

```
 {
    :message => "Hello, world",
    :name=>  "name here",
    :link=>  "http://blabla.com",
    :caption=> "Note:  stars",
    :description => " a long sentence",
    :picture => "http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg",
    :source =>  "another url"
  }
```

but if I do the same things with graph api using javascript sdk,  the picture can be posted to the wall.

here is the same questions the other guys asked. any help? thank you very much.

[Problem with post a picture in Facebook Wall with Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535657/problem-with-post-a-picture-in-facebook-wall-with-graph-api)

[Picture posting NOT working with facebook Graph API anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502883/picture-posting-not-working-with-facebook-graph-api-anymore)